# How to add new table's in the existing Database in MVC asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a database and I want the table which Model Class will create that should get appended to an Existing Database without creating the whole database again.

Is this possible without being dropping and creating again the whole database?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Generate the SQL query for dropping/recreating the whole database (but don't execute it, obviously).

Then search through the query to find anything in which your new table is mentioned.

Usually you'll end up with:

- CREATE TABLE statement
- Primary Key creation for your table
- Any number of Foreign Key creation (depends on how many you are using)

Paste all those snippets (in order!) in a new query, and only execute that query.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late, but this may help:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-new-field